# How to split dictionary according to key and value into multiple dictionaries using indexes?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to select only a set of elements (e.g elements belonging to menu no1) that fufils my condition, and append the elements into a new dictionary. Each set of elements, (e.g or menu no.1) has starting key - `'Miniwok_Stall_Menu1'` and ending key - `'remark:@Miniwok_stall_Menu1'`.
dictionary here: https://pastebin.com/viDw1snv
My current plan is to:
1) Find selected set of elements that fufils the conditions: Day of week - must exist in the first value for menu to be selected `e.g Mon in Monday,Tuesday...` and time of meal - the value in the remark key has to be the same as time_of_meal, `e.g 'None'`
2) Using enumerate to get start and ending indexes of selected set of elements.  `#e.g(0,4,5,9)`
3) using a for loop, create a new dictionary based on the indexes. (containing only the selected set of elements)
4) expected output is a dictionary with the exact same format as the original, but with only selected set of elements.

```
#raw_list_stallinfo is assigned to the dictionary in pastebin.
selected_stalls = []
Day_of_week = 'Mon'
time_of_meal = 'None' #None is inclusive of breakfast,lunch and dinner

for raw_list_idx, raw_list_key in enumerate(raw_list_stallinfo.keys()):
    #select the menu number based on day of week
    if Day_of_week in raw_list_stallinfo[raw_list_key]:

        #day_of_week is always found in the first index of a set of elements
        selected_stalls.append(raw_list_idx)



print(selected_stalls)
```

Questions:
1) How to get indexs of ending key of selected set of elements?(which is the index of the remark key) One set can have more elements than the other so will not be able to hardcode. The starting key is already found in selected_stalls. I am looking for `(starting key of menu2, ending key of menu2, starting key of menu3, ending key of menu3)`
2)How to get the index of the key containing 'remark' to use for validation for second condition `time_of_meal?`
`if raw_list_stall_info[remark_key_index] == time_of_meal:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your `for` loop in dictionary comprehension:

```
selected_stalls = []
Day_of_week = 'Mon'
time_of_meal = 'None'

raw_list_stallinfo = {'MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': 'Monday_Tuesday@Wednesday', 'Item1: Seafood HorFun@MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': '$4.50', 'Item2: Fish HorFun@MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': '$3.50', 'Item3: Chicken Horfun@MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': '$3.50', 'remark:@MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': 'None', 'MiniWok_Stall_Menu2': 'Thursday_Friday@Sunday', 'Item1: Seafood Fried Rice@MiniWok_Stall_Menu2': '$4.50', 'Item2: Salted Fish Fried Rice@MiniWok_Stall_Menu2': '$3.50', 'Item3: Chicken Fried Rice@menu2': '$3.50', 'remark:@MiniWok_Stall_Menu2': 'None', 'MiniWok_Stall_Menu3': 'Monday_Tuesday_Wednesday_Thursday_Friday@Sunday', 'Item1: Chicken Porridge@MiniWok_Stall_Menu3': '$3.00', 'Item2: Century-egg porridge@MiniWok_Stall_Menu3': '$4.00', 'remark:@MiniWok_Stall_Menu3': 'Breakfast Only'}

raw_list = {raw_list_idx: raw_list_key  for raw_list_idx, raw_list_key in enumerate(raw_list_stallinfo.keys()) if Day_of_week in raw_list_stallinfo[raw_list_key]}
selected_stalls.append(raw_list)
print(selected_stalls)
```

This will give the output:

```
[{0: 'MiniWok_Stall_Menu1', 10: 'MiniWok_Stall_Menu3'}]
```

To find the `time_of_meal` location:

```
location = {i: k for i, k in enumerate(raw_list_stallinfo.values()) if k == time_of_meal}
print(location)
```

Which gives the locations as:

```
{4: 'None', 9: 'None'}
```

Then to find the `remark` without hard-coding you can marry it up with the location above:

```
remark_location = {i: k for i, k in raw_list_stallinfo.items() if k == time_of_meal}
print(remark_location)
```

Which returns the full Key and Value:

```
{'remark:@MiniWok_Stall_Menu1': 'None', 'remark:@MiniWok_Stall_Menu2': 'None'}
```